# nodeJS TypeError of Content Type

Tags: node.js

My code is here i am facing Type error of **Content Type** when start the server.

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');

var port = 4000;
http.createServer((req,res) => { 
    if(req.method==="GET"){
    res.writeHead(200, {"Content Type": "text/html"});
    fs.createReadStream("./public/index.html", "UTF-8").pipe(res);
}
else if(req.method==="POST")
{
    var data = " ";
    req.on("data", function(chunk) {data += chunk;});
    req.on("end" , function(){
        res.writeHead(200,{"Content Type": "text/html"});
        res.end('${data}');
    });
}

}).listen(port);
console.log(port)
```

[Error i am facing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ek90K.png)

Comment: Synatx error it has to be content-type

Answer (score 0):

It should be `Content-Type`, with dash:

```
res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
```